# Making others feel good with words - Is it Punya Karma?

Tags: punyam

If I make some one feel good, irrespective who he is(good/evil, poor or rich, Boss or subordinate), by saying good words, good compliments, by praising for their achievements or good qualities. Can it be considered as Punya Karma?

What Hindu Dharma Sastra is saying about this?

Answer (score 5):

Two things are to be noted. Regarding [truth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ioPLF53GXU)

1. सत्यं ब्रूयात् प्रियं ब्रूयात् न ब्रूयात् सत्यमप्रियम् |
   प्रियं च नानृतं ब्रूयात् एष धर्म: सनातन: ||

   One should always speak the truth. One should always speak kind words. Do  not  speak truth that hurts. Do not lie for the sake of pleasing.
2. Regarding Praise, Jagadguru Sri Chandrasekhara paramacharya of Sri Kanchi Kamakoti Peetham once in his Anugraha Bhashanams [said that](https://mahaperiyavaa.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/divine-thoughts-108/)

   "If we praise a person for his good qualities, he will have greater enthusiasm to cultivate them further. But there should be restraint in praise too - praise indeed is a tricky thing. That is why the wise say :

   प्रत्यक्षे गुरवः स्तुत्या परोक्षेमित्र बान्धवाः । कर्मान्ते दास भृत्याश्च पुत्रा कदाचन ।।

   Isvara and the Guru alone may be praised directly. Friends and relatives, instead of being praised to their face, must be spoken of well to others. You may praise your servant after the job entitled to him is done. (It is like patting a horse after ride). You may never praise your son"

As far as Punya is considered, since Isvara has given us this body and organs, in order to put them to good use for pleasing God (Paramesvara/Narayana Preetyartham), one should always try to speak kind and soothing words to anyone in difficulty to get them out of it or for the welfare of others because Speech is a special gift given only to human in the whole 8400000 Jivas

Answer (score 2):

In the [**Thirumantiram**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirumantiram), tenth volume of 12 volumes of Tirumurai,  Thirumoolar mentions among those that pleases Lord Shiva. Thirumoolar is one of the 18 Siddhars and also one among the 63 Nayanars.

> Yaavarkumaam Iraivanuku Oru Pachillai
>   Yaavarkumaam Pasuvuku Oru Vaayurai
>   Yaavarkumaam Unnumpothu Oru Kaipidi
>   Yaavarkumaam Piraruku Innurai Thanei
>
> (From Mudhal than^thiram (First Tantra) paththAm thirumuRai (tenth Tirumurai))

**English Translation**:

Even using just a leaf like Bilva to worship daily
  Feeding a mouthful to a cow
  A handful of food for someone else while eating
  A comforting word to someone else

**A comforting and pleasing speech pleases Lord Shiva**.

Comment: Hello . .I have edited part of your answer. Please further  edit your answer and make it more simple and understandable by explaining the portion  related to topic of  the question . Add some more description and chapter /verse no. etc